# How do I send multiple SOAP Requests in a loop: PHP?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, loops, soap

Am using PHP curl to do SOAP requests to a webservice, I have an array of IDs of over 500 items, for each ID, I send a SOAP request and get a XML response for which I test some parameters and generate/store in a variable. Unfortunately, I can only loop through 9 IDs of the array, over which I get a "500 Server error" in firebug on a jquery post.
How do I loop through ALL these 500 items? Could it be done with parallel connections OR multi-threading? If so how do you it in PHP curl?

Here is my sample code.

```
<?php 
$VehicleIDs = "153,106,128,149,121,123,125,133,130,115,124,116,102,100,101,103,144,113,...........";//over 500 items
$VehicleIDsArray = explode(",", $VehicleIDs);

for($i=0; $i <= count($massVehicleIDsArray); $i++){
            $soapUrl = "http://xxx.asmx";
            $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                              <soap:Body>
                                <GetInUseEventsForVehicleID>
                                  <VehicleID>'.$massVehicleIDsArray[$i].'</VehicleID>
                                </GetInUseEventsForVehicleID>
                              </soap:Body>
                            </soap:Envelope>';

        $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "SOAPAction: xxx", // your op URL
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                );
        // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $soapUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // xml request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // converting
        $response = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);

        // converting
        $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

        // convertingc to XML
        $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);   

        /*....................

        MORE CODE TO COMPARE EACH SOAP RESPONSE

        ...................*/
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: curl multi init can help - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks base problem is in low time limit http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time, and yes curl supports parallel execution http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php , there are some open-source libs for parallel curl executing.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4091-PHP-Retrieve-multiple-pages-simultaneously.html

https://github.com/Fivell/Utfy

https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl

and so on.
 But you still  might hit the maximum execution time or the memory limit though

Answer (score 0):

Another posibility is that you call the wsdl method in a php many times in same page

create before a client connection and later do something similar

```
$params1 = array(xml nodes);
$client->WSDLMETHOD($params1);

echo $client->__getLastRequest();
echo $result = $client->__getLastResponse(); 

//reapeat this and you will do two soap request
$params2 = array(xml nodes);
$client->WSDLMETHOD($params2);
echo $client->__getLastRequest();
echo $result = $client->__getLastResponse();
```

Comment: Remember: do not initialize multiple times SoapClient class.

I made this mistake and after 2.000 cycles the request silently fails.